# Exercise watches that can monitor irregular heart beats

Tags: exercise-equipment, heart-rate-monitor

Are there any exercise watches such as Apple Watch and fitbit watch that can monitor irregular heart beat? My heart beats irregularly for each hours approximately. I also plan to wear this watch to run. Is there any suggestion? Thank you very much!

Comment: Not that i am aware of. But personally, I wouldn't measure my hearts condition on a sports watch. You should contact your doctor/cardiologist (with excerise test) to determine your condition & what sports you're allowed to do...

Comment: My doctor concluded that I am healthy. My condition does not endanger my life. It just needs to be monitored, which is what I am trying to do now, to monitor as a precaution. I hope my explaination helps.

Comment: Unfortunately, this really isn't on topic for the site. It's not about using the equipment to improve your workout, it's about using monitoring equipment for  medical necessity. With a little bit of rewording, it might be on topic at Health.se, but I'm not aware of anything like a [Holter Monitor](https://www.nlm.nih.gov/medlineplus/ency/article/003877.htm) for personal use. Also, by irregular do you mean varying rate, or actual PVC type irregularities?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can get Polar HR monitor with HRV (Heart Rate Variability)
[Polar HRV](http://www.polar.com/us-en/support/Heart_Rate_Variability__HRV_) Using these kind of watches you will see the rate between each heart beat intervals.